# Trying to append objects to an Enumerable in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach, append, iteration

I'm doing a C# exercise to create an operation that takes a collection, performs a function on each object in the collection, and returns a collection of modified objects.

My code is currently as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<U> Accumulate<T, U>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, U> func)
{
    IEnumerable<U> output = Enumerable.Empty<U>();

    foreach (T item in collection)
    {
        output.Append(func(item));
    }

    return output;
}
```

This is only returning an empty collection, and I have no idea why.

I have tried creating a copy of the item in the foreach after seeing this approach in another thread, like so:

```
foreach (T item in collection)
    {
        U copy = func(item);
        output.Append(copy);
    }
```

but that didn't solve anything.

I did some research but couldn't really find any examples doing exactly what I'm trying to do here. I read some things about closure, but couldn't really understand it, as I'm new to C#.

Comment: Just so you know, this could also be implemented in Linq: `var output = collection.Select(x => SomeFunction(x));`

Comment: Append won´t *modify* your collection, it *returns* a new one. This applies to all LINQ-methods, by the way.

Comment: or more abbreviated:  `var output = collection.Select(SomeFunction);`

Comment: To add to what @HimBromBeere has said, if you check [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt823360(v=vs.110).aspx) you can see that `Append()` _returns_ the IEnumerable that has the latest appendages

Comment: @RuiJarimba yes, I just wanted to show that lamba was possible too

Comment: @maccettura yes I understood :)

Comment: Thank you both, using .Select worked, and the information about .Append returning a new collection is very helpful. Cheers.

Comment: Assuming you were going to keep the same approach as originally written, why wouldn't you just use a `List<U>`? You don't get any benefit here from trying to use `IEnumerable<U>` as an implementation detail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your actual question: The reason it isn't working is because

```
output.Append(func(item));
```

doesn't change `output` - instead, it returns a new sequence which is `func(item)` appended to `output`. Thus when you eventually return `output` you are just returning the original, empty sequence.

You could make yours work by this simple change:

```
output = output.Append(func(item));
```

However, this is not an efficient approach - you're much better off using  [`yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield), by modifying your method as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<U> Accumulate<T, U>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, U> func)
{
    foreach (T item in collection)
    {
        yield return func(item);
    }
}
```

Although note that that is more simply expressed as:

```
public static IEnumerable<U> Accumulate<T, U>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, U> func)
{
    return collection.Select(item => func(item));
}
```

But it is useful to know about how to do this with `yield` so that you can write solutions to more complex Linq-like problems.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had no idea of the proper use of yields.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when I want to achieve this kind of behaviour, I make use of C# Iterators.
They are so usefull when you want to process an iteration on some kind of data and, at each iteration, return a value that is appended to your resulting collection.

Take a look at the docs: [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)

Comment: Link in inglese solo per favore

Comment: Fixato, chiedo scusa

Comment: Non ti preoccupare